# WCF related - System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:

Tags: wcf

I've tried different configurations with no success...this error is the latest error with these configuration.....Any ideas?

Note: I'm hosting the service from a console app on a server and then calling the service from a web app (the client) located on another server.

I DON"T care about security so I set the security mode="None".

The error I get:

`System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote endpoint has sent an unrecognized fault with namespace, http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope, name Sender, and reason The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.. The channel could not be opened.`

Also, I did notice this error in the BackupServerService.wdl file that was put onto the web app client app when I added the service reference.

These nodes are underlined and It states that: `the schema referenced from this location in your document contains errors`.
    "Cannot resolve the schema location attribute"

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://"I removed the IP"/Application/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService?xsd=xsd0" 
                namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://"I removed the IP:8000"/Application/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService?xsd=xsd1"
                namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

My client web.config file looks like: (Note: the "IP address" and "userPrincipalName" are both fictitious for this posting.)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService" 
               closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
               receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
        <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://"I removed the IP:8000"/Application/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService/BackupServerService"
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService"
              contract="ServiceReference1.IBackupServerService" 
              name="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService">
      <identity>
        <userPrincipalName value="xxxxx-415-B\djbrown" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="BackupServerPassword" value="Danspassword" />
    <add key="StorageFolderName" value="C:\Backupstorage-backups" />
    <add key="FileZilla" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
     app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BackupServerServiceLibrary.BackupServerService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="BackupServerServiceLibrary.IBackupServerService"
                  bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityConfig">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My service interface:

```
Namespace BackupServerServiceLibrary

  <ServiceContract()>
  Public Interface IBackupServerService

      <OperationContract()> 
      <WebInvoke(Method:="GET")>
      Function DeleteBySpaceIdProcess(ByVal strIpAddress As String, ByVal strPassword As String, ByVal iBackupSpaceId As Integer) As Boolean

      <OperationContract()> 
      <WebInvoke(Method:="GET")>
      Function AddBackupSpaceProcess(ByVal strIpAddress As String, ByVal strPassword As String, ByVal iBackupSpaceId As Integer, ByVal iPublicFtpAccountId As
        Integer, ByVal strPublicFtpAccountPassword As String, ByVal iPrivateFtpAccountId As Integer, ByVal strPrivateFtpAccountPassword As String) As Boolean

      <OperationContract()> 
      <WebInvoke(Method:="GET")>
      Function UpdateFtpAccountsProcess(ByVal strIpAddress As String, ByVal strPassword As String, ByVal iBackupSpaceId As Integer, ByVal iFtpAccountId As Integer,
        ByVal strFtpAccountPassword As String, ByVal strAccountType As String) As Boolean

    End Interface
End Namespace
```

One of the methods of the service that I am calling from the web app (client):  (Code reduce to just show relevant parts)

```
Namespace BackupServerServiceLibrary

    <ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)>
    Public Class BackupServerService
        Implements IBackupServerService

        Public Function DeleteBySpaceIdProcess(ByVal strIpAddress As String, ByVal strPassword As String, ByVal iBackupSpaceId As Integer) As Boolean Implements IBackupServerService.DeleteBySpaceIdProcess

            strEncryptedBackupServerPassword = GetAppSetting(strKeyPassword)

            If strEncryptedBackupServerPassword = strPassword Then
                strStorageFolderName = GetAppSetting(strkeyStorageFolderName)
                strFileZillaFilepathAndName = GetAppSetting(strKeyFileZilla)

                If ((strStorageFolderName = "Not Found" Or strStorageFolderName = "Error") Or (strFileZillaFilepathAndName = "Not Found" Or strFileZillaFilepathAndName = "Error")) Then
                    Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: during delete of space - cannot find the storage folder name or FileZilla entry in the app config. Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString())
                Else
                    strVhdFilepathAndName = "strStorageFolderName" & "\" & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & "\" & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & ".vhd"
                    If File.Exists(strVhdFilepathAndName) Then
                        Try
                            UnmountVHDFile(strStorageFolderName & "\" & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & "\DiskpartUnmountVHDScript.txt", strVhdFilepathAndName)
                            Try
                                DeleteSpacesFolderAndFiles(strStorageFolderName & "\" & iBackupSpaceId.ToString(), strStorageFolderName & "\Boot-Scripts\" & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & "-boot.txt")
                                Try
                                    DeleteXMLEntries(strFileZillaFilepathAndName, iBackupSpaceId)
                                    Try
                                        ReloadFileZillaConfig()
                                    Catch ex As Exception
                                        Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: during delete of space - reload of FileZilla failed. Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & " from: ReloadFileZillaConfig() ---> " & ex.Message)
                                    End Try
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: during delete of space - Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & " from: DeleteXMLEntries() ---> " & ex.Message)
                                End Try
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error during deletes:  Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & " from: DeleteSpacesFolderAndFiles() ---> " & ex.Message)
                            End Try
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: during delete of space - Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString() & " from: UnmountVHDFile() ---> " & ex.Message)
                        End Try
                    Else
                        Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: VHD file does exist. Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString())
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Throw New System.Exception("Critical Error: during delete of space - password not found. It's invalid. Space Id: " & iBackupSpaceId.ToString())
            End If

            Return bSuccess = True
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Web app (client) service call:

```
Dim proxyClient As New BackupServerServiceClient()

Try
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Step 2: Call the service operations.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Call the service operation.
    proxyClient.DeleteBySpaceIdProcess(strBackupServerIpAddress, 
    strBackupServerPassword, Request("backupspaceid"))

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Step 3: Closing the client gracefully closes the connection and cleans up resources.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    proxyClient.Close()                        '
    Catch timeout As TimeoutException
        ' Handle the timeout exception.
        bSuccess = False
        lblMessage.Text = "Critical Error - from web service - at timeout. " & 
        timeout.ToString()
        proxyClient.Abort()
    Catch commException As CommunicationException
        ' Handle the communication exception.
        bSuccess = False
        lblMessage.Text = "Critical Error - from web service - at commException. " 
        & commException.ToString()
        proxyClient.Abort()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Handle the exceptions from the web service call.
        bSuccess = False
        lblMessage.Text = "Critical Error - from web service. " & ex.Message
    Finally
        If proxyClient.State = CommunicationState.Faulted Then
            bSuccess = False
            If lblMessage.Text = "" Then
                lblMessage.Text = "Critical Error - network issue on call to the 
                web service. Contact IT, do not continue."
            Else
                lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text & " ---> Additional error - 
                 network issue on call to the web service."
            End If
            proxyClient.Abort()
        End If
    End Try
```

Lastly, when I enter the URL in the chrome browser. the page appears to be all good.

Comment: A couple of things come to mind to check.  First, based on your posted service config, it looks like you're using a WCF Library.  Libraries do not use their own config files - they use the app/web.config of the application that is using the library.  Did you copy the relevant WCF settings to the config of your console application?

Comment: Secondly, your client is using contract `ServiceReference1.IBackupServerService`, and your service is using `BackupServerServiceLibrary.IBackupServerService`.  The .NET framework will not see those two items as the same, even if the code is identical, because the namespaces are different.  I'm not sure it that's the issue here, however.

Comment: For the 2nd idea, I modeled my service off of the instructions in the MSDN tutorial. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx.....they too have them named differently yet it worked. So I'm not sure if that is the issue here either.

Comment: For the 1st issue, I did not copy the service app.config entries to the host console app.config. I will try that.